# Getting the owners for all SharePoint sites

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I need to get the owners of all SharePoint sites (both classic, modern and SharePoint sites connected to Teams).. there are about 1000 sites
`your text`

I have run the following but it only gives me limited owners and not all the owners and for some sites only listing the site admins as owners instead of the actual site owners. I know and have verified through SharePoint Admin centre that every site has owners/has members in the site owners group.

$AdminCenterURL = “https://XXX-admin.sharepoint.com” ;
$CSVPath = “C:\Temp\SiteOwners.csv”

```
 #Connect to SharePoint Online and Azure AD
Connect-SPOService -url $AdminCenterURL
Connect-AzureAD

#Get all Site Collections
$Sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL

 $SiteOwners = @()
 #Get Site Owners for each site collection
 $Sites | ForEach-Object {
 If($.Template -like ‘GROUP*’)
 {
 $Site = Get-SPOSite -Identity $.URL
 #Get Group Owners
 $GroupOwners = (Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $Site.GroupID | Select -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName) -     join "; "
 }
 Else
 {
 $GroupOwners = $.Owner
 }
 #Collect Data
 $SiteOwners += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
‘Site Title’ = $.Title
‘URL’ = $_.Url
‘Owner(s)’ = $GroupOwners
}
}
#Get Site Owners
$SiteOwners

#Export Site Owners report to CSV
$SiteOwners | Export-Csv -path $CSVPath -NoTypeInformation`
```

`

Can anyone help, where I have gone wrong, or let me know if there is a better way?
I need to get all the owners of all the SharePoint sites in the tenancy, there are over 1000 sites in the tenancy

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It appears the majority of the problems with your code come from copy/pasting from the internet. First is the single quotes around `GROUP*` are special curly quotes. Second you are missing several `_` in your `$_.xyz` references. Finally some bad habits such as creating an array `$blah = @()` and then `+=` which just creates a copy of the original array. Not a huge issue if it's not a big list but there is absolutely no reason for it. Other bad habit is old school creation of a custom object. I've rewritten the code and tested on my end, looks good.

```
$AdminCenterURL = “https://XXX-admin.sharepoint.com”
$CSVPath = “C:\Temp\SiteOwners.csv”

Connect-SPOService -url $AdminCenterURL
Connect-AzureAD

$sitelist = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL

$siteownerlist = foreach($site in $sitelist){
    $ownerlist = if($site.Template -like '*group*'){
        Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $site.GroupId | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName
    }
    else{
        $site.Owner
    }

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Site Title' = $site.Title
        URL          = $site.Url
        'Owner(s)'   = $ownerlist -join '; '
    }
}

$siteownerlist | Export-Csv -path $CSVPath -NoTypeInformation`
```

If you plan to use this long term, it's recommended you replace the AzureAD commands with microsoft graph commands.

**EDIT**

Perhaps the sharepoint online/exchange online approach can provide the data you are looking for.

```
$adminurl = 'https://yourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com'

Connect-SPOService -Url $adminurl
Connect-ExchangeOnline

Function Get-GroupOwner{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [string]$SiteURL
    )

    $Owners = $SiteOwners = $Null

    $sposite = Get-SPOSite -Identity $SiteURL

    $Groupid = if($sposite.Template -match  "TEAMCHANNEL#\d"){
        $sposite.GroupId
    }
    else{
        $sposite.RelatedGroupId
    }

    $Owners = if($GroupId.Guid -eq "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"){
        "Deleted group"
    }
    else{      
        try{ 
            Get-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity $GroupId.Guid -LinkType Owners -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        catch{
            "Possibly deleted Office 365 Group"
        }
    }

    $SiteOwners = if($Null -eq $Owners){
        "No owner located"
    }
    elseif($Owners -isnot [string]){
        ($Owners | ForEach-Object {
            "{0} ({1})" -f $_.DisplayName,$_.PrimarySmtpAddress
        }) -join '; '
    }

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Site   = $siteurl
        Owners = $SiteOwners
    }
}

# Check that we are connected to Exchange Online and SharePoint Online
$ModulesLoaded = Get-Module | Select-Object Name

If (!($ModulesLoaded -match "ExchangeOnlineManagement")) {
    Write-Host "Please connect to the Exchange Online Management module and then restart the script" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    break
}

If (!($ModulesLoaded -match "Microsoft.Online.Sharepoint.PowerShell")) {
    Write-Host "Please connect to the SharePoint Online Management module and then restart the script" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    break
}

$sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit All |
    Select-Object Title, URL, StorageQuota, StorageUsageCurrent, Template |
        Sort-Object StorageUsageCurrent -Descending

$totalspostorageused = [Math]::Round(($sites.StorageUsageCurrent | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum /1024,2)

$report = foreach($site in $sites){
    $siteowners = $Null

    Write-Host Processing site: $site.Title -ForegroundColor Cyan

    $sitetype,$siteowners = switch -Regex ($Site.Template) {
        "RedirectSite#\d"            {"Redirect",(Get-GroupOwner $site.url).Owners}
        "GROUP#\d"                   {"Group-enabled team site",(Get-GroupOwner $site.url).Owners}
        "TEAMCHANNEL#\d"             {"Teams Private Channel",(Get-GroupOwner $site.url).Owners}
        "REVIEWCTR#\d"               {"Review Center",(Get-GroupOwner $site.url).Owners}
        "APPCATALOG#\d"              {"App Catalog",(Get-GroupOwner $site.url).Owners}
        "STS#\d"                     {"Team Site","System"}
        "SPSMSITEHOST#\d"            {"Unknown",(Get-GroupOwner $site.url).Owners}
        "SRCHCEN#\d"                 {"Search Center",(Get-GroupOwner $site.url).Owners}
        "EHS#\d"                     {"Team Site - SPO Configuration","System"}
        "EDISC#\d"                   {"eDiscovery Center",(Get-GroupOwner $site.url).Owners}
        "SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#\d"      {"Site page", "System"}
        "POINTPUBLISHINGHUB#\d"      {"Communications Site","System" }
        "POINTPUBLISHINGPERSONAL#\d" {"OneDrive for Business",(Get-GroupOwner $site.url).Owners}
        "POINTPUBLISHINGTOPIC#\d"    {"Office 365 Video","System"}
    }

    $usedGB = [Math]::Round($site.StorageUsageCurrent/1024,2) 
    $percenttenant = ([Math]::Round($site.StorageUsageCurrent/1024,4)/$totalspostorageused).tostring("P")           

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        URL           = $site.URL
        SiteName      = $site.Title
        Owner         = $siteowners
        Template      = $sitetype
        QuotaGB       = [Math]::Round($site.StorageQuota/1024,0) 
        UsedGB        = $usedGB
        PercentUsed   = ([Math]::Round(($site.StorageUsageCurrent/$site.StorageQuota),4).ToString("P")) 
        PercentTenant = $percenttenant
    }
}

$report
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am still having the same problem, where for lots of sites, it is listing the site admins instead of the site owners.  For other sites it is correctly listing the site owners. I have verified that those sites where it is listing the site admins have site owners through SP admin centre

Comment: I added a different solution, maybe it can get you closer to your goal. If nothing else, maybe it can provide some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification - currently only 1 member of the "Site admins" are being listed for each site instead all the members of the "Site members" group which is what I need. There are the following groups for classic SharePoint sites - Site admin, Site owners, Site members and Site visitors - it is the Site owners members that I am interested in.

[image: SP groups]

Comment: This looks like a clarification to the question rather than an answer. Instead you can edit your question if you'd like to add clarifications, or add comments to the question, or to other answers

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this article to get all the owners of all the SharePoint sites by using PowerShell:

[SharePoint Online: Get the Site Owner using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/02/get-sharepoint-online-site-owner-using-powershell.html)

Comment: I have already seen that page/site prior to posting on here, I get the same issue of site admins being listed as site owners instead of listing the actual site owners